# Chemplants doc example failed

Tags: tikz-pic

I want to use check valve pic as described on [chemplants](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/contrib/chemplants/chemplants-doc.pdf) doc at page 54, but I get an error saying it's not defined. I know it could be an error of the package, but I want to be sure and see if it's defined in another way. It's possible to print all tiks/pics available? or how should I face this problem ?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemplants}
%%%

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0) { check valve = main };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/pics/check valve', to which you passed 'main', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Currently I create my own command, but it's really a crude attempt (I'm new at tikz, so I don't know how to define coordinates for a pic and it doesn't even see proportional when I use the scale option)

```tex
\tikzset{
    check-valve/.pic={
        \draw (0,-2mm) -- (0,0);
        \node[minimum size=3pt,draw,circle,fill, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {};
        \draw (0,0) -- (4mm,-2mm);
        \draw (4mm,-2mm) -- (4mm,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any other errors (in particular before the error message you quote)? Is `chemplants` installed? To answer these questions it would already help if you could upload the whole `.log` file of your LaTeX run to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com

Comment: To use `check valve` you need `chemplants` 2021/09/25 v0.9.9 (see [related diff](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemplants/chemplants.sty?r1=60606&r2=60605&pathrev=60606) from texlive's svn repo, starting from line 2098). You may have the previous version (2019/11/19 v0.9.8) installed. Overleaf's texlive 2021 also provides v0.9.8, hence no `check valve` available.

Comment: Note the doc you download from CTAN's webpage `ctan.org/pkg/<pkg name>`  is always the latest one, hence may be ahead of your local installation.

Comment: I don't know. For the example I used XeLaTeX in TexWorks (MikTeX) and didn't work, I downloaded TeXMaker and it did.

Comment: @EduardoJiménez, is it still a problem? Please let us know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me in Texmaker (MikTex), with quick build options being PdfLatex or LuaLatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemplants}
%%%

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0) { valve = main };    
    \pic at (2 ,0) { check valve = main };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Some guesses why your compile might fail:

- hidden typo
- tikz not installed

Comment: I'm using XeLaTeX in TexWorks (MikTeX) and I used also Overleaf to build the example